# PHP cURL with API Key and Secret (Postman)

Tags: php, api, postman

I'm working with an API which is made by a classmate. I used Postman to generate the PHP cURL for the connection, with Authorization Basic. This works perfectly. Now, I want to get rid of the Authorization Basic and use my own API Key & Secret (password). Are there any good ways to do this?

Thanks in advance!

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "Some link here",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Basic //something here",
        "cache-control: no-cache",

    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    $result = json_decode($response,true);
}
```

Comment: Is the server setup and expected to take an API key + secret?

Comment: Need more inputs to give a proper answer. Without knowing how your api authenticates the users, we cannot really tell.

Comment: I suppose so. Postman generates the Authorization Basic by itself. I use the Key & Secret to make a GET within postman. And when I only use the API Key, I get an error which says that I don't have the permission. I guess because there is no Secret involved.

Comment: I already figured it out. Thanks!